# Google Cloud Storage serves up old image when file names are the same

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Running into an issue with hosted images in Google Cloud Storage.  When an image gets uploaded to a destination and has the same name as a file there it replaces the file, however Google continues to serve up the old image at the URL.

If I go into the bucket I can see the preview of the new image, however, clicking the link will open a window and show the old image.

How do I fix this so it shows the updated image?

Comment: Make sure your browser cache is not the one actually showing you the image (browser debugger -> networking). Also, check your Cloud Storage cache metadata settings.

Comment: Setting max-age=0 for the metadata on the image was the key, thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction @JohnHanley

Comment: @RockwellRice, please post your comment as an answer so that other community members with similar questions as yours would find your answer helpful.

Answer (score 3):

So I had to set the `max-age` to `0` when uploading the image.

```
  const options = {
    expires: Date.now() + 1 * 60 * 1000, // 1 minute,
    fields: { 
      'x-goog-meta-test': 'data',
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', <----------- this is what I needed
     },
  };
```